# Getting List Items using WCF and Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, user-information-list

I am attempting to loop through all the items in a sharepoint List and get the firstname of the requestor.

Requestor is a UserInformationListItem type

```
var source = dc.Requests;

listBox1.Items.Clear();
foreach (var user in source) {
    string name = user.Requestor.FirstName;
    listBox1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

The code that i'm using works fine for getting the ID's of the list items but when it comes to getting anything that would be inside a userinformationlistitem it get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Answer (score 0):

Found the Solution:

```
var requestedBy = dc.UserInformationList.Where(i => i.Id == user.RequestorId).FirstOrDefault();
var requestedByUserID = requestedBy.UserName;
listBox1.Items.Add(requestedByUserID);
```